# POST text data as file in form

Tags: html, file-upload, forms, http-post

Is it possible to  POST some XML data i have as string as file input type from a html form.

The case is i have a form like

```
form action="target.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   <input type="file" name="file" id="file"><br>
   <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

I have some xml data as string in my javascript code and i want to sent that string from the form as if it was uploading as a file with the file input tag

Thanks

Comment: With ajax you can but not with a regular form submit.

Comment: Yes with ajax is what i am looking for.Can you drop me some pointers how to do this with ajax.Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your browsers supports [XMLHttpRequest level 2](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest2/) and the html5 [FileApi](http://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI/) you can do the following

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest;
var blob = new Blob([xmlString], {type:'text/xml'});
var data = new FormData();
data.append('file', blob, 'filename.xml');
xhr.open('POST',url, true);
xhr.send(data);
```

If your browser doesn't support these apis then you'll have to build your post body manually

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('POST', url, true);
var boundary = '----'+(new Date()).getTime();
xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'multipart/form-data; boundary='+boundary);
var data = ['--'+boundary,
    'Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="filename.xml"',
    'Content-Type: text/xml','',xmlString,'--'+boundary+'--',''].join('\r\n');
xhr.send(data);
```

Comment: Yes the manual way works well.I already implemented that way.Anyways thanks for the answer :)