# Send Custom HTTP Body with AJAX POST request

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, http, post

How do I send a custom HTTP body with my POST AJAX request in plain Javascript (not JQuery)? I am actually trying to send a JSON file in the body. I can set the custom header fields but can't find how to set HTTP body.

below is the code

```
function calculateorder() {

    document.getElementById("finalize").style.display = "inline";

    url1 = "https://ethor-prod.apigee.net/v1/stores/";    
    url2 = "/orders/calculate?apikey=wSgbv9PE8aJhDOI17vvTUX1NlAceUXG7";

    url = url1 + store_id + url2;

    var xmlhttp;
    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            alert(xmlhttp.responseText);
        }
    }

    xmlhttp.open("POST", url, true);
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
    xmlhttp.send(JSON.stringify(calculate));
}
```

When I used the same headers and JSON file with Rested (a OSX HTTP client) It works perfectly

Comment: Are you trying to read the posted data as a file on the server? If so see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16223485/post-text-data-as-file-in-form

Comment: I am not sure. I did the same thing in Java using Data output stream and it worked. I guess server just reads it as a JSON stream.

Comment: Where do I put my JSON in that example?

Comment: Replace the xml with your json

Comment: Tried it. Did not work

Comment: Maybe you should post your server side code

Comment: I don't have access to that at the moment.

Comment: try send data by tool to make sure your server side work. take a look: Postman https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman-rest-client/fdmmgilgnpjigdojojpjoooidkmcomcm

Comment: I am using Rested for MAC and the server side is working perfectly

Answer (score 2):

Add parameter in `XmlHttpRequest` Obeject's `.send()` method

Like this:

```
xhr.send('username=me');
```

Send JSON Format Data `myData` Like this:

```
xhr.send(JSON.stringify(myData));
```

Comment: What if I am sending a JSON file?

Comment: a file in your computer? or just a json format data?

Comment: Json format data. The json file is perfect. I checked it using Rested. But for some reason, it is not working when used with AJAX.

Comment: try `xhr.send(JSON.stringify(myData));`

Comment: any error message on the console? or try `console.log(JSON.stringify(myData))` to debug

Comment: there is no issue with JSON. When I do alert(JSON.stringify(myData)), the json file is in proper format and is exactly what is expected.